# Vehicle Routing with pre-determined number of drivers with different work schedules

Tags: java, routes, jsprit

I am working on a try and buy service in which I will be having one fixed depot along with pre-defined number of drivers (each with different 6 hour shifts). I have a list of customer orders which I have to deliver at different 1 hour hard windows. Every customer takes an hour to try the items and after that either the same driver or a different driver has to pickup up the item from the customer within an one hour hard window and delivery it back to the depot before the driver's work shift expires.

I would like to use jsprit to solve this optimisation problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your customers offer only 1 time window, you can solve this problem with jsprit. Just specify n vehicles where n is also the number of drivers and shifts. Assign them a shift by specifying earliest and latest start of the vehicle. Then, specify your customers, e.g. as services. Here, you can define how long the service takes (serviceTime), the time window of the service start, a vehicle capacity demand (e.g. the transported item weights 10kg and has a volume of 100) etc.. However, if your customers offer multiple time windows, you cannot yet solve it with jsprit (this is what we are currently working at).